# named table with an expandable range of cells (Excel 2003)

Tags: excel

In Excel 2003 I have table like this:

[image]

How can I create named table with an expandable range of cells (not using VBA)?

Comment: With a dynamic range name - many examples abound on Google

Answer (score 0):

@Brettdj has provided a solution but for want of an answer as such:

1. Put `=RAND()*0+201` in B2 – this does not affect the result of B2 but since =RAND is a volatile function it will force an update of the named range array as and when that is changed.
2. Define the range for the name as `=OFFSET($B$2,0,0,COUNT($B$2:$B$200),1)` (or adjust $200 to something more suitable).

If the range is named say `Bcolumn` now `=SUM(Bcolumn`) would return 3,618 as would `=SUM(B2:B19`) in your example, but while the latter would remain as 3,618 if 201 were inserted in B20, the former would then return 3,819.